# Help to interpret a trace to find a sql server deadlock

Tags: sql-server-2008

First of all I must say that I have somewhat basic knowledge of sql server and with that I'm trying to figure out how to resolve a deadlock.

I ran dbcc traceon (1204, -1), executed the culprit code and finally executed the xp_readerrorlog stored proc which gave me the following output:

```
Deadlock encountered .... Printing deadlock information
Wait-for graph
NULL
Node:1  
OBJECT: 9:1093578934:0         CleanCnt:2 Mode:IX Flags: 0x1
 Grant List 2:
 Grant List 3:
   Owner:0x000000008165A780 Mode: IX       Flg:0x40 Ref:2 Life:02000000 SPID:57 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x0000000082F00EC0
   SPID: 57 ECID: 0 Statement Type: EXECUTE Line #: 1
   Input Buf: RPC Event: Proc [Database Id = 9 Object Id = 1877581727]
Requested by: 
  ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000082E02E80 Mode: S SPID:56 BatchID:0 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000000826EE538) Value:0x81a6f9c0 Cost:(0/1492)
NULL
Node:2  
APPLICATION: 9:0:[Proligent Analytics]:(6ff56412) CleanCnt:2 Mode:X Flags: 0x5
 Grant List 2:
   Owner:0x000000008165DE40 Mode: X        Flg:0x40 Ref:1 Life:00000000 SPID:56 ECID:0 XactLockInfo: 0x0000000082E02EC0
   SPID: 56 ECID: 0 Statement Type: OPEN CURSOR Line #: 27
   Input Buf: RPC Event: Proc [Database Id = 9 Object Id = 1966630049]
Requested by: 
  ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000082F00E80 Mode: X SPID:57 BatchID:0 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000000827B8538) Value:0x83e29d40 Cost:(0/250576)
NULL
Victim Resource Owner:
 ResType:LockOwner Stype:'OR'Xdes:0x0000000082E02E80 Mode: S SPID:56 BatchID:0 ECID:0 TaskProxy:(0x00000000826EE538) Value:0x81a6f9c0 Cost:(0/1492)
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to use this to find out what's going on. I've read that you can get the stored procedure that is getting locked but I don't know how.

Please a few pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `select db_name(9), object_name(1093578934,9), object_name(1966630049,9), object_name(1877581727,9)` should give you some of the objects.

Comment: Thank you Martin, this is exactly what I needed. Why didn't you post this as an answer to get the rep points?

Comment: @MartinSmith why dont you post your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 3):

As @Martin Smith says in his comment: select db_name(9), object_name(1093578934,9), object_name(1966630049,9), object_name(1877581727,9) should give you some of the objects.